# Error found when visitng my newly cloned project to local. localhost/laravel/public

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

After successfully cloning my laravel project on live repo. I install the composer directly to the project folder, configure the database successfully run migrate successfully.

after which, when I visited localhost/laravel/public I got this error "RuntimeException in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid." and I don't know what to do next. I am a newbie in this field so I hope somebody could help me with this.

Comment: did you run `php artisan key:generate` ?If not, try after running that command

Comment: yes I did.. it says: Application key  {nYbksaf.... set successfully @VishalSh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I got it already.. So strange because after doing "php artisan key:generate" it didn't generate 32 strings just "SomeRandomString"..

I just replace it with any string.. 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-installation-runtime-exception-in-compiledphp-line-6911 and then it solves the problem